# new column based on other column 2 rows in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have to create a new column in a dataframe when a column row values are a specific sequence. i tried the below code but needs some help in achieving this.

```
sno     name    points  place
1       Bob     10      Z1
2       Jack    10      Z2
3       Rian    10      Z1
4       Vick    10      Z1
5       Jick    10      Z1
6       Rams    10      Z1
7       Venk    10      Z2
```

when place in z1 and next row place column has z2 then in the new column should have same value for both rows. something like below

```
sno     name    points  place   newid
1       Bob     10      Z1      1
2       Jack    10      Z2      1
3       Rian    10      Z1      NA
4       Vick    10      Z1      NA
5       Jick    10      Z1      NA
6       Rams    10      Z1      2
7       Venk    10      Z2      2
```

filtered the data when above condition met but, after that i cant able to add new column and have same value for both rows

```
fdf = df["place"].eq('z1') & df["place"].shift().eq('z2')
fdf['newid'] = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close in terms of logic. We have 2 conditions:

1. The current row is Z1 and the next row is Z2 (`c1`)
2. The current row is Z2 and the previous row is Z1 (`c2`)

We can take the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of the first condition `c1` to create the `new_id`, then we can OR (`|`) the 2 conditions together to filter to only rows that match either condition, and allow index alignment to handle introducing the `NaN` values:

```
c1 = df['place'].eq('Z1') & df['place'].shift(-1).eq('Z2')
c2 = df['place'].eq('Z2') & df['place'].shift().eq('Z1')
df['newid'] = c1.cumsum()[c1 | c2]
```

`df`:

```
   sno  name  points place  newid
0    1   Bob      10    Z1    1.0
1    2  Jack      10    Z2    1.0
2    3  Rian      10    Z1    NaN
3    4  Vick      10    Z1    NaN
4    5  Jick      10    Z1    NaN
5    6  Rams      10    Z1    2.0
6    7  Venk      10    Z2    2.0
```

---

Breakdown of steps in a DataFrame:

```
c1 = df['place'].eq('Z1') & df['place'].shift(-1).eq('Z2')
c2 = df['place'].eq('Z2') & df['place'].shift().eq('Z1')
breakdown_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'place': df['place'],
    'c1': c1,
    'c2': c2,
    'c1 cumsum': c1.cumsum(),
    'c1 | c2': c1 | c2,
    'cumsum filtered by c1 | c2': c1.cumsum()[c1 | c2]
})
```

| `place` | `c1` | `c2` | `c1 cumsum` | `c1 | c2` | `cumsum filtered by c1 | c2` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Z1 | True | False | 1 | True | 1 |
| Z2 | False | True | 1 | True | 1 |
| Z1 | False | False | 1 | False | nan |
| Z1 | False | False | 1 | False | nan |
| Z1 | False | False | 1 | False | nan |
| Z1 | True | False | 2 | True | 2 |
| Z2 | False | True | 2 | True | 2 |

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sno': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'name': ['Bob', 'Jack', 'Rian', 'Vick', 'Jick', 'Rams', 'Venk'],
    'points': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
    'place': ['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z1', 'Z1', 'Z1', 'Z1', 'Z2']
})
```

Comment: thanks, its working but, instead 1, 2 if we want a specific number then how can we achieve this? for example i want a Fibonacci sequence OR a GUID